# HTTP GET request with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, xmlhttprequest

First of all, I am VERY new with JS so sorry for the simple question.
I have a search box in a webpage which the user should type some input into it.
After that, I need to perform a HTTP GET request to some address (say: http://m.mywebsite.com/AppService.svc/searchitems?param=userValue when the param parameter is the user input (in the below sample it is John Doe).
So far I tried with this way, but nothings happen when I click somewhere in the webpage. Hope some of you can explain me how to do it right.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            'url' : 'http://m.mywebsite.com/AppService.svc/searchitems',
            'type' : 'GET',
            'data' : {
                'param' : 'John Doe'
            },
            'success' : function(data) {
                if (data == "success") {
                    alert('request sent!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server returns "success" ?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: first place to start troubleshooting is in the browser console. Get to know how it works...it's your javascript lifeline! Find the actual request in network tab and inspect it

Comment: Start by checking the console F12 > Network tab see if the request is being sent and the response is "success".

Comment: Thanks everyone, I just looked at the JS console and see the following message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://m.mywebsite.com/AppService.svc/searchitems%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2+%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. I really don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use `addEventListener()` function with `document` object. You should use something like that:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 0):

this works (if the 'url' is correct and accept GET requests).
The url you are using should receive GET requests and answer something (in this case, "success" if "param" is passed), check it before proceeding.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://m.mywebsite.com/AppService.svc/searchitems',
            type : 'GET',
            data : { param : 'John Doe' }
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data == "success") alert('request sent!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, eventually I succeed to run this code (I disabled Chrome security) but now instead of "success" I get nothing. I tried to alert the data variable and I get [object object]. What does it mean?

Comment: It means that the js code is correct, what you need to know is what you're returning from the appservice.svc page.

So I think you need to learn something more about the server side of ajax.

Try to post here your appservice.svc code, the problem is there.